# Searching Alfresco Share site members with Lucene / FTS

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, alfresco, alfresco-share

Is it possible to search Alfresco Share site members with lucene or fts-alfresco? For example, I would like to find all the site members with lastname "Smith".

Additionally, is it possible to search users that have certain permissions to a site folder or document?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot search site members directly using Lucene, because indexing does not have any data related to that. What you need to do is use siteService to get that information. You can use any of these API.Second one return Map so may be more relevent.

**org.alfresco.service.cmr.site.Site.SiteService**

```
listMembers(String shortName, String nameFilter, String roleFilter, boolean collapseGroups, SiteService.SiteMembersCallback callback)

    or 

listMembers(String shortName, String nameFilter, String roleFilter, int size)
```

You first need to access all site members using API of siteservice and then iterate over them to get your required users.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do this with lucene or not, but if you want to find users ,below webscript is usefull.

If you see in below url `nf=NameOfUsers` parameter specifies name of user.If youare not specifying `nf` Parameter ,it will return all users.

http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/sites/demo/memberships?size=250&nf=te&authorityType=USER

For more details of above webscript, you can use below URL.
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/script/org/alfresco/repository/site/membership/memberships.get

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to search Alfresco Share site members with fts-alfresco, because site members belong to an Alfresco group.

For example, the following query returns members of the SWSDP site:

```
PATH:"/sys:system/sys:authorities/cm:GROUP_site_swsdp//*" AND TYPE:"cm:person"
```